# Square root of expectation squared equals square root of squared expectation?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, expectation

I have in my notes that:

$$\text{CorrCoeff}(x_i,a+bx_i)=\frac{\mathbb{E}[(x_i-\mathbb{E}[x_i])(bx_i - b\mathbb{E}[x_i])]}{\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[(x_i - \mathbb{E}[x_i])^2] \mathbb{E}[(bx_i - b\mathbb{E}[x_i])^2]}} $$

Which is understandable: co-variance divided by the respective standard deviations. But then how come: $\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[(x_i-\mathbb{E}[x_i])^2]} = \mathbb{E}[x_i - \mathbb{E}[x_i]]$. This does not make sense, because when you square root something like: $\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[x_i-\mathbb{E}[x_i]]^2}$ you would get $\mathbb{E}[x_i-\mathbb{E}[x_i]]$, but clearly $\mathbb{E}[(x_i-\mathbb{E}[x_i])^2] \neq \mathbb{E}[x_i-\mathbb{E}[x_i]]^2$, or are they?

Comment: Yes they do not hold in general (except in degenerate case). Where do you see them? Or why do you have this doubt?

Comment: I have then that the first expression evaluates to: $\frac{b}{|b|}$ and I think that can only happen when the square root of the expected value of the square is the same as the square root of the square of expected value. So I need to understand why I can write $\mathbb{E}[(x_i - \mathbb{E}[x_i])^2]$ as $\mathbb{E}[(x_i - \mathbb{E}[x_i])]^2$, so that I can take a square root and arrive at the $b/|b|$ result

Comment: Unless I am being really silly right now and in fact $\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[(x_i-\mathbb{E}[x_i])^2]} = \mathbb{E}[x_i - \mathbb{E}[x_i]]$. But I can't see how I can square root of this expression. Can I take the square root operator inside the expectation brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I see the problem. I have not carefully read your first equation previously.

By the linearity of the expectation, the covariance is also linear:

$$ \text{Cov}[X, aY] = \mathbb{E}[(X - \mu_X)(aY - a\mu_Y)] 
= a \mathbb{E}[(X - \mu_X)(Y - \mu_Y)] 
= a \text{Cov}[X, Y]  $$

And for variance, it is well known that
$$ \text{Var}[aX] = a^2\text{Var}[X] $$
and you can verify by yourself if you want.

Now, in your equation, it is a special case: The numerator is

$$ \text{Cov}[X, a + bX] = b\text{Cov}[X, X] = b\text{Var}[X]$$

The denominator is

$$ \sqrt{Var[X]Var[a + bX]} = \sqrt{b^2Var[X]^2} = |b|Var[X]$$

So

$$ \text{Corr}[X, a + bX] = \frac {b\text{Var}[X]} {|b|Var[X]} = \frac {b} {|b|}$$

It is also a well known result: when both variables are perfectly linear, then their correlation will be equal to $\pm 1$, depending on the sign of the coefficient.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.